Is it possible to create multiple pipenvs on a computer for multiple projects?
I'm learning about virtual environments in Python 3.9.2 and I learned that we can use pipenv rather than pip and venv to create virtual environments for our project. However, after some trial with different project directories I've made I have been unable to create another folder where pipenv stores packages I've downloaded, unlike pip and venv, which I can use to create an isolated virtual environment for each project and download packages into a folder in the virtual environment of each project.
When I enter pipenv --venv into the terminal in VScode it shows only one directory where the packages are stored, and when I enter pipenv install <name_of_package> it goes into that same directory, it doesn't create a new one for each project which I thought it would. This is essentially the same as downloading packages globally, since I only have one pipenv directory for my one machine.

I was able to solve the issue without altering any environment variables. First I downloaded and installed the most recent version of Python and then uninstalled the older version that I had previously, in my case downloading Python 3.12 and removing Python 3.9.2. I made sure to remove any files related to the older version on my computer, and then to confirm that the later version was installed I typed the following command in command prompt (using Windows): python -V. After that I used pip to install pipenv again, then I had to locate the path to python.exe and enter that as as command in command prompt. The file was hidden, so finding it was a little tricky, but the way I found it was by going into the Start menu and entering python 3.12 in the search bar. One of the results said python 3.12(64 bit); I right-clicked that result and clicked open file location, which opened the folder with the shortcut to python.exe. Then I right-clicked that shortcut and clicked File Insight, which opened a Norton Antivirus window containing some details about the file as well as a link to the location of python.exe to which the shortcut directs. When I clicked that it opened a File Explorer window showing the executable file in its parent folder and the path to it beside the search bar, so I used that path in command prompt to specify the version of Python pipenv should use, like this:
pipenv --python path\to\python

After that I had to delete the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files that the previous version of pipenv had made for Python 3.9 by opening up File Explorer and using the search bar to find it, then using command prompt I made another folder in my user account on my computer, changed the directory of command prompt to that folder and using pipenv shell I was able to make a virtual environment for that folder. To verify that the problem was solved I made another folder and was able to make another virtual environment for that folder as well.

You can create multiple virtual environments for multiple projects with one instance of pipenv.

Create a directory/folder for your project if it does not exist.
mkdir project1


Change directory to your project's folder
cd project1


Activate your virtual environment
pipenv shell


Repeat these steps for each project where you want to create a virtual environment.

By default, pipenv stores virtual environments in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ (%USERPROFILE%.virtualenvs on Windows) directory. The virtual environment's name will be made up of the project's name together with a hash of the project's path. For example, a project named project1 will have a virtual environment similar to project1-o8XPyapT.
Every time you run pipenv commands within the project1 directory, pipenv will always activate the project1-o8XPyapT virtual environment. To recreate the virtual environment for the project, deactivate the virtual environment using the exit command and then delete the virtual environment using pipenv --rm command.
To save the virtual environment in your project's folder, set the PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT environment variable with a value of True (PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1) from a command or terminal window. Alternatively, you can create a .env file at the root of your project and update the file with the PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT environment variable with a value of True.
I hope that helps.

I tried your instructions and pipenv continues to open the same virtual environment for every project whenever I type pipenv shell

I have edited the answer to take your comment into account.

How do I change the environment variable? I tried typing PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 in the command prompt (in Windows) but it says it's not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

If using the command prompt, use set PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 or
$env:PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 if using PowerShell.
